# HEVC: NAL unit trace file for each NUL unit produced by the encoder

Tags: video, video-processing, hevc, h.265

I'm using HM 14.0 as a reference. Is there a way to get some specific information about NAL units like

```
(a) type
(b) num_bytes
(c) frame_no
(d) decode_time
(e) priority
(f) timestamp
```

The first two I can have it through annexBbytecount, but what about the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference codec comes with a built in tracer which is quite powerful!

Enable it like this:

```
diff --git a/source/Lib/TLibCommon/TComRom.h b/source/Lib/TLibCommon/TComRom.h
index 5a59809..1930809 100644
--- a/source/Lib/TLibCommon/TComRom.h
+++ b/source/Lib/TLibCommon/TComRom.h
@@ -158,7 +158,7 @@ extern const UChar g_aucDCTDSTMode_Hor[NUM_INTRA_MODE];
 extern       Char   g_aucConvertToBit  [ MAX_CU_SIZE+1 ];   // from width to log2(width)-2

 #ifndef ENC_DEC_TRACE
-# define ENC_DEC_TRACE 0
+# define ENC_DEC_TRACE 1
 #endif
```

As an example, I encoded and decoded the first 20 frames of `BQMall_832x480_60.yuv`
with trace enabled.

After encoding/decoding using:

```
./TAppEncoderStatic -c ../cfg/encoder_intra_main.cfg  -c ../cfg/per-sequence/BQMall.cfg
./TAppDecoderStatic -b str.bin
```

trace-files are produced (rather huge ones!)

```
$ ll -rt 
total 247100
drwxrwxr-x 12 xx xx      4096 jun 27 10:01 ../ 
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xx xx   2912618 jun 27 10:06 TAppDecoderStaticd*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xx xx    627714 jun 27 10:06 TAppDecoderStatic*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xx xx   4036611 jun 27 10:06 TAppEncoderStaticd*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xx xx   1133295 jun 27 10:06 TAppEncoderStatic*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xx xx     87319 jun 27 10:06 annexBbytecountStaticd*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xx xx     29963 jun 27 10:06 annexBbytecountStatic*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xx xx    369365 jun 27 10:06 convert_NtoMbit_YCbCrStaticd*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xx xx    113252 jun 27 10:06 convert_NtoMbit_YCbCrStatic*
-rw-rw-r--  1 xx xx    442122 jun 28 21:29 str.bin
-rw-rw-r--  1 xx xx  11980800 jun 28 21:29 rec.yuv
-rw-rw-r--  1 xx xx 168288021 jun 28 21:29 TraceEnc.txt    <----
drwxrwxr-x  2 xx xx      4096 jun 28 21:31 ./
-rw-rw-r--  1 xx xx  62975377 jun 28 21:31 TraceDec.txt    <----
```

Have a look at `TraceEnc.txt` and `TraceDec.txt` they contain everything you need to know!

Comment: Thank you, I managed to create the TraceEnc.txt so far but the only part I see that is useful to me is only type which I also get using annexBbytecount. Can you please tell me which is the frame_no, or timestamp or num_bytes? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found frame_no is POC and slice type. Currently I found no timestamp, number of bytes and priority.

Comment: Is there a way to find the number of bytes of each packet in the TraceEnc file?

Comment: Don't think so. I'm currently on vacation with only gsm-edge coverage which makes it hard to visit SO. I'll help you when I'm back in civilization again :-)

Comment: OK Fredrik, Thank you. I'll wait! Enjoy yourself!

Comment: Is there a way to find the arrival time of each packet or frame in the TraceEnc.txt file?